# Wordpress - Adding to Redux Theme Options using Child Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, redux-framework

I am using a wordpress theme that has it's own framwork which is based upon redux framework I think. I am modifying this theme using a child theme. I want to add to the Theme Options in the backend and I found a function within the files of the parent theme that seems to be exactly what I need:

```
/*
 *
 * Custom function for filtering the sections array. Good for child themes to override or add to the sections.
 * Simply include this function in the child themes functions.php file.
 *
 * NOTE: the defined constansts for URLs, and directories will NOT be available at this point in a child theme,
 * so you must use get_template_directory_uri() if you want to use any of the built in icons
 *
 */
function add_another_section($sections){
    //$sections = array();
    $sections[] = array(
        'title' => __('A Section added by hook', 'swift-framework-admin'),
        'desc' => __('<p class="description">This is a section created by adding a filter to the sections array. Can be used by child themes to add/remove sections from the options.</p>', 'swift-framework-admin'),
        // Redux ships with the glyphicons free icon pack, included in the options folder.
        // Feel free to use them, add your own icons, or leave this blank for the default.
        'icon' => trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'options/img/icons/glyphicons_062_attach.png',
        // Leave this as a blank section, no options just some intro text set above.
        'fields' => array()
    );

    return $sections;
}
//add_filter('redux-opts-sections-twenty_eleven', 'add_another_section');
```

I have added this function to my child theme's functions.php and uncommented the add_filter. However, this does not seem to work and no new section has been added.

I came across this discussion [elsewhere](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124179/modify-redux-framework-options-in-child-theme) which suggests the name of the function needs to be changed (I was getting the same error mentioned on there). I have done that and it still won't work.

Here is what I have in my child theme functions.php

```
function add_another_section_bl($sections){
    $sections = array();
    $sections[] = array(
        'title' => __('A Section added by hook', 'swift-framework-admin'),
        'desc' => __('<p class="description">This is a section created by adding a filter to the sections array. Can be used by child themes to add/remove sections from the options.</p>', 'swift-framework-admin'),
        // Redux ships with the glyphicons free icon pack, included in the options folder.
        // Feel free to use them, add your own icons, or leave this blank for the default.
        'icon' => trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'options/img/icons/glyphicons_062_attach.png',
        // Leave this as a blank section, no options just some intro text set above.
        'fields' => array()
    );

    return $sections;
}
add_filter('redux-opts-sections-twenty_eleven', 'add_another_section_bl');
```

I wasn't sure if the filter name 'redux-opts-sections-twenty_eleven' needs editing as it mentions the twenty eleven theme. I have tried it with different theme names at the end instead of twenty_eleven and that had no effect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! On a side note I have been able to accomplish adding new options to Theme Options by copying over the whole framwork folder into my child theme and defining the path to the framework in the child theme's functions.php. I just felt that there should be a much slicker, neater way to achieve this and I thought that function sounded perfect.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lead dev of Redux Framework here. This solution only works if you're using Redux Framework 3.1+. If you have an older version, install the Redux Framework plugin and it will override the version inside your theme.

First go to the current option panel. Open up a javascript console (use chrome or firefox) and type: `redux.args.opt_name`. That will echo out a name. Copy that and paste it into this function replacing `OPT_NAME` with the name that was echo'd out:

```
function add_another_section_bl($sections){
    $sections = array(); // Delete this if you want to keep original sections!
    $sections[] = array(
        'title' => __('A Section added by hook', 'swift-framework-admin'),
        'desc' => __('<p class="description">This is a section created by adding a filter to the sections array. Can be used by child themes to add/remove sections from the options.</p>', 'swift-framework-admin'),
        // Redux ships with the glyphicons free icon pack, included in the options folder.
        // Feel free to use them, add your own icons, or leave this blank for the default.
        'icon' => trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'options/img/icons/glyphicons_062_attach.png',
        // Leave this as a blank section, no options just some intro text set above.
        'fields' => array()
    );

    return $sections;
}
// In this example OPT_NAME is the returned opt_name.
add_filter("redux/options/OPT_NAME/sections", 'add_another_section_bl');
```

Good luck!

** UPDATE **

Also with the Redux API you can easily add a new section that way.

```
Redux::addSection(array(
        'title' => __('A Section added by hook', 'swift-framework-admin'),
        'desc' => __('<p class="description">This is a section created by adding a filter to the sections array. Can be used by child themes to add/remove sections from the options.</p>', 'swift-framework-admin'),
        // Redux ships with the glyphicons free icon pack, included in the options folder.
        // Feel free to use them, add your own icons, or leave this blank for the default.
        'icon' => trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'options/img/icons/glyphicons_062_attach.png',
        // Leave this as a blank section, no options just some intro text set above.
        'fields' => array()
    ))
```

That makes it a wee bit easier using our API I believe we released in Redux 3.2...

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It was just the filter name as you suggested there. I got the correct filter name from the theme dev and it now works. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey Dovy, I tried your function, but it seems to replace all the sections of the parent theme with this one. will it be possible to keep all the options from parent theme, and add new section from child theme?

Comment: Remove the `$sections = array();` to use the existing section. By running this line, you're resetting the panel completely.

Comment: Awesome, you saved my day

Answer (score 0):

If you are using redux options with plugin your filter won't work inside a theme
for that make sure you put code inside a plugin.

Here is code that will work with theme and plugin as well!

```
function add_social_media_options($sections) {
$sections[] = array(
    // Redux ships with the glyphicons free icon pack, included in the options folder.
    // Feel free to use them, add your own icons, or leave this blank for the default.
    'icon' => 'el-icon-wrench',
    'title' => esc_html__('Social Media Settings', 'textdomain'),
    'desc' => esc_html__('These are settings social media link', 'textdomain'),
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'id' => 'facebook_link',
            'type' => 'text',
            'url' => true,
            'title' => __('Facebook link', 'textdomain'),
            'compiler' => 'true',
            //'mode' => false, // Can be set to false to allow any media type, or can also be set to any mime type.
            'desc' => __('', 'textdomain'),
            'default' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 'twitter_link',
            'type' => 'text',
            'url' => true,
            'title' => __('Twitter link', 'textdomain'),
            'compiler' => 'true',
            //'mode' => false, // Can be set to false to allow any media type, or can also be set to any mime type.
            'desc' => __('', 'textdomain'),
            'default' => ''
        ),

    )
);

return $sections;
}

add_filter("redux/options/redux_demo/sections", 'add_social_media_options');
```