# WordPress & Redux Framework - Using current_theme_supports to control Redux sections

Tags: wordpress, redux-framework

Similar to [Wordpress - Adding to Redux Theme Options using Child Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799026/wordpress-adding-to-redux-theme-options-using-child-theme)

I'm am looking to control Redux sections with current_theme_supports($feature), so that if a theme supports a feature, a section won't be displayed. Eg if colors are managed by the theme (and the theme declares support), don't display the color section, but if not, display it.

I have got the filter working great with redux/options/option_name/sections, but at the point the filter is run global $_wp_theme_features is null.

Any tips on the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lead dev of Redux here. Delay the loading of your option panel to the init hook. Basically your panel is loading before $_wp_theme_features is populated. The earliest you can run it is after_setup_theme. That's when the theme files (functions.php) has loaded.

Once you do that, all should be gravy.  :)

Comment: Super awesome, Dovy, thanks. I used after_theme_setup as recommended and a priority of 100 (10 didn't seem to cut it).